# Probability that the signal will pass through the scheme.

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that the signal will pass through the scheme?
>
> Every relay is open with the probability of $p$ and closed with the probability of $q$.
>
> [image]
>
> And if we got a signal at the end what conditional probability do we have that E was open?

The only way I can see is to consider every possible path from the beginning to the end, but it is to bulky. Are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two separate cases:

1) If $E$ is closed then the signal will pass through the scheme iff 
$$((\text{A is closed}) \lor (\text{C is closed})) \land ((\text{B is closed}) \lor (\text{D is closed})).$$
That is
$$\neg((\text{A is open}) \land (\text{C is open})) \land \neg((\text{B is open}) \land (\text{D is open}))$$
and the probability is $q\cdot(1-p^2)\cdot(1-p^2)$.

2) If $E$ is open then the signal will pass through the scheme iff 
$$((\text{A is closed}) \land (\text{B is closed})) \lor ((\text{C is closed}) \land (\text{D is closed})).$$
That is
$$\neg(\neg((\text{A is closed}) \land (\text{B is closed}))) \land \neg((\text{C is closed}) \land (\text{D is closed}))))$$
and the probability is $p\cdot(1-(1-q^2)\cdot(1-q^2))$.

Therefore the probability that the signal will pass through the scheme is 
$$q(1-p^2)^2+p(1-(1-q^2)^2)=1-2p^2-2p^3+5p^4-2p^5$$
where we set $q=1-p$. Note the result is $1/2$ for $p=1/2$ (see a plot [HERE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201-2*p%5E2%2B5*p%5E4-2*p%5E3-2*p%5E5%20for%20p%20from%200%20to%201)).

Are you able to answer to the second question?

Comment: Will the second answer be $p\cdot(1-(1-q^2)\cdot(1-q^2)) / [q\cdot(1-p^2)\cdot(1-p^2) + p\cdot(1-(1-q^2)\cdot(1-q^2)) ]$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In the statement you say "Every relay is open with the probability of $p$". So for example if $p=0$  every relay is closed and $1-2p^2-2p^3+5p^4-2p^5=1$ that is the signal will pass through the scheme for sure.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

The following table shows the output depending on the inputs and the probabilities belonging to the actual gate combination. ($1$ for closed, $0$ for open.)

[image]

**The sum of the probabilities belonging to the green area is the probability that the signal gets through.**

The sum of the probabilities in the black-framed area ($P$) is the probability that the signal gets through and the E gate is open.

The sum of the probabilities in the red-framed area ($Q$) is the probability that the E gate is open.

**$\frac PQ$ is the conditional probability we are seeking.**

Comment: According to OP every relay is open with the probability of $p$ (not $q$). Anyway, after swapping $p$ and $q$, we get the same final result.

Comment: How did you create the table? What soft were you using?

Comment: @trafalgarLaww: Excel accompanied with  human brain : )